# how to set highest priority of intent filter dynamatically?

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to android.I have developed an application Text Off.Text Off application blocked undesired calls and text.It is smoothly working for 4.2 or lower version but it's text block functionality not working for kitkat 4.4 version and call disconnect after one ring. I am totally black that what do i.  I am using following code .

**this is service page code ServiceReciever.java**

```
package com.rsoft.callListener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class ServiceReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    private static TelephonyManager telephony;
    private static DeviceStateListener phoneListener;
    private static boolean firstTime=true;

    public ServiceReciever(Context context)
    {
        telephony=(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        phoneListener=new DeviceStateListener(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if(firstTime)
        {
            telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            firstTime=false;
        }
    }

    public void stopListening()
    {
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        firstTime=true;
    }

}
```

**this page for SMS Receiver**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        this.context=context;
        blockSms(intent);
    }

    public void blockSms(Intent intent)
    {
        String MSG_TYPE=intent.getAction();
        final String android_id = Secure.getString(context.getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        // Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Received: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         //toast.show();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
       final SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) 
        {
            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

            //final BlockedContact cn=CallBlockerService.blackList.get(smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress());
            //final BlockedContact cn=CallBlockerService.blackList.get(android_id);
            //if(cn!=null && cn.getName().equals("1")||cn!=null && cn.getName().equals("3"))
            final String Status=TextOffService.deviceStatus;
            if(Status!=null && Status.equals("1")||Status!=null && Status.equals("3")|| Status != null
                    && Status.equals("5"))
            {
                abortBroadcast();
                //final String android_id = Secure.getString(context.getApplicationContext()
                        //.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss");
                        Date date=new Date();
                        String currentDate=dateFormat.format(date);

                        //LOG FORMAT --> TITLE;;MESSAGE;;NAME;;NUMBER;;HOUR;;BODYMESSAGE;;SEPARATOR
                        String message="Text Blocked;;A message from "+smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress().replace("+", "")+" was blocked at "+currentDate+";;"+smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress().replace("+", "")+";;"+currentDate+";;"+smsMessage[0].getMessageBody().replace("\n", "")+";;\r\n";
                        sendSmsByManager(smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress().toString(),"I can't reply to your text at this time Driving ");
                        writeInLog(message);
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceUniqueID",android_id));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MyLog", message));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ContactNo", smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress().replace("+", "")));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Created_Date", currentDate));
                        // getting JSON string from URL
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_create_product, "POST", params);

                        // check log cat for response
                        Log.d("Create SMS log", json.toString());
                    }
                });

                t.start();
            }
```

**now this page register  receivers CallBlockerService.java**

```
 service = new ServiceReciever(getApplicationContext());
 sms = new SmsReceiver();
        registerReceiver(service, new IntentFilter(
                "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
        registerReceiver(service, new IntentFilter(
                "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"));
        IntentFilter intentSMS = new IntentFilter(
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        intentSMS.setPriority(2147483647);
        registerReceiver(sms, intentSMS);
```

**Please help me how to restricted incoming call and text**

Comment: Can you provide more details or show explicitly what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Android where you can block incoming calls is Android 2.2

In Android 2.3 and followed you cannot manage for incoming calls.

For blocking calls you should set voicemail option at contact to "1" and provide non existed voicemail number.